# How to stack images in Matlab,

Tags: matlab, image-processing, stack

For example. I have 10 gray scale images (same size) with the data image between [0.1] in the same folder. Now I want to make the stack for these images by using data image as (1.mat, 2.mat...10.mat). Could you tell me please how to code it in Matlab. Thank you very much :)

Comment: what about simply summing your matrices together: 1.mat + 2.mat + ... + 10.mat?

Comment: Dear,

I think it is not a plus or multiply, it means stack image, for example you can see the image in this link. Thanks a lot :)

http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/images/what-is-an-image-sequence.html

Comment: Gotcha! Is this http://angeljohnsy.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-create-video-from-still-image.html helpful at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
imagestack = cat( 3, image1, image2, image3, ... );
```

Or

```
imagestack = zeros( [size(image1), 10 ] );
imagestack(:,:,1) = image1;
imagestack(:,:,2) = image2;
.
.
.
```